A Question about the Sealing of the Spirit in Ephesians
From Ephesians 1:13 and Ephesians 4:30 what is the meaning that I am sealed with the Spirit ?
Does it imply that the Holy Spirit is just a mark in my life or what role and personality of the Spirit is being indicated in my life ?

In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise . . .  [Ephesians 1:13 KJV]


And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption [Ephesians 4:30 KJV]


It is best always to explicitly quote the cited verses. That would save the readers from having to look them up, and would avoid confusion such as was created by what looks like a mistake in the chapter number.

Welcome to SE-BH. I have edited your question to correct the typo and to demonstrate how you may highlight referenced quotations. I hope this agrees with your intentions. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Up-voted +1.

The question first asks about Ephesians 1:13, as to what the "sealing" of the Spirit means, for those people who are so "sealed". The very next verse gives insight into the answer.

"Which is the earnest of our inheritance until the redemption of the
purchased possession, unto the praise of his glory." Ephesians 1:14
A.V.

The N.A.S.B. renders "earnest" as "pledge". The R.S.V. renders it as "guarantee". The N.I.V. renders it as "a deposit guaranteeing". So, verse 14 explains that the sealing of the Holy Spirit in believers assures them - but of what? Verse 14 says they are now guaranteed the promised inheritance that Christians have. What they have been promised is an inner assurance of the Spirit living in them, that they are, indeed, sons of God, who will inherit the reality of all the promises of God to his children. Even now, they know the reality of having been purchased by the shed blood of Christ. The Spirit within assures them by opening up their understanding to what Christ has done for them, and for the glory of God. This transforms their understanding and their living and their dying. This paragraph shows the value of understanding a verse simply by reading on to the next verse - context (probably the most valuable exegetical tool students have.)
This should help deal with the second question, as to the implications of being so sealed; how should that affect one's life? It is the presence of the Holy Spirit himself who will enable the massive change in relationship to God to work out in daily living, as one believes and puts faith in this miracle of being sealed. The Christian begins to waken up to being "raised with Christ"; to become aware of heavenly realms, invisible now but that will be experienced when the inheritance is realised. A study of Romans chapter 8 should open that up. Because of the guarantee, the Christian can cry "Abba, Father" knowing they are heirs (vss. 15-17). They can endure any suffering for Christ's name sake, retaining joy and confidence in what is to come; knowing nothing can now separate them from the love of God that is in Christ. A study of the whole of that 8th chapter will help answer the second question.
To conclude, here is quote expressing the kind of wondrous realisation of what being sealed by the Spirit means to those getting the answer to the first question. This is based on the first chapter of Ephesians, further showing the need to get the whole context of that verse asked about, which is in the middle of that chapter:

"Those whom the Father chose in Christ are given the place of sonship,
a nearness in love exclusive to the only begotten Son in the bosom of
the Father...
The redemption [vs. 14] shows what a mighty release, what a tremendous
loosing, took place at the cross: for sinful man could not have been
further away. The distance appeared infinite, the guilt immeasurable,
the barrier insurmountable, and the difficulty insuperable...
redemption is rooted and grounded in the shedding of the blood of
Christ. It is the foundation of all the doctrine, 'We have redemption
through his blood'. We have it; no conditions. We have it through his
blood. When that blood was shed, everything else, like believing and
receiving, follows from that.
Redemption secures the inheritance, pays the price, sounds the
jubilee, and ensures the entering into everlasting glory free from
every enemy and from the hand of all the hateful foes, of every last
one of the redeemed." The Ministry of the New Testament magazine,
article Redemption, pp.27-31, Vol. 34, Number 3, Autumn 2019, John
Metcalfe Publishing Trust

The Holy Spirit teaches believers the things of Christ, pointing to him, so that those who are sealed with the Holy Spirit of promise begin to understand those promises and what Christ did to secure their redemption. Those who speak with joy about such revelations and assurances show evidence of being so sealed.

Seal (Mirriam-Webster Dictionary): Something that confirns, ratifies, or makes secure: guarantee, assurance.
These particular verses speak to this security guarantee in the Holy Spirit.  However other verses point to the more active role the Spirit has in our living our lives, for instance:
*[Jhn 14:26 ESV] 26 But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he will teach you all things and bring to your remembrance all that I have said to you.[Rom 15:13 ESV] May the God of hope fill you with all joy and peace in believing, so that by the power of the Holy Spirit you may abound in hope.
[1Th 1:6 ESV] 6 And you became imitators of us and of the Lord, for you received the word in much affliction, with the joy of the Holy Spirit,[Rom *

I am on the point of up-voting but hesitating, hoping you will reference the Greek original rather than Merriam-Webster and the English translation . . . . . . .

The noun form of sealed (σφραγίς G4973) is seen in Rev 5:2,3 sealing the book which ...no man in heaven, nor in earth, neither under the earth, was able to open the book..., demonstrating the security of the seal of God.

Thank you. And how would that concept (the sealing of a book) be applied to the Person of the Holy Spirit and to our own union, in that One Spirit, with Jesus Christ and with God, the Father ?

The seal is the security guarantee by God.  Which is much more reliable than that which men attempt and fail at, such as in [Mat 27:66 ESV] So they went and made the tomb secure by sealing the stone and setting a guard.

Thank you. Up-voted +1.
